# How to help in debugging an app (in this case Qt based)?

Tags: debugging

Ok, so first of all - I'm not a programmer. But there are apps my work relies on and I'd like to help in debugging those. 
So what would you consider a useful bug report? What kind of data you would like to get to ease nailing the issue down? Are there any tools I could use that would provide additional data you would find useful?

It got me thinking after recently I upgraded to a new version of 3d package and the linux build on my Fedora 21 works rather badly. For example on Gnome (on Xfce its ok) none of the popovers inside main app window (the app is Qt based) work. What's more interesting popovers work in floating windows of the app. As you might imagine I'm really interested in fixing those and thus I'd like to send revalant info.

http://i814.photobucket.com/albums/zz63/pj_pics/various/popoversbug_zpsscgat2xw.jpeg~original

Answer (score 0):

You'll quickly learn that one of the greatest assets your program can have when it comes to debugging is logging. Logging general information is fine, but exceptions are the gold nuggets you are looking for when it comes to debugging your system.

You should record, as a minimum,

- The type of exception
- The date and time it was raised
- Any additional information from the exception that might be pertinent.
- The callstack.

Hope that has helped you out...

Comment: yeah Martin, I try to be strict when recording the issues I'm experiencing and when sending those to the programmers / customer support. But as a non-programmer it is difficult for me to judge what's important. Also often I'm not aware of the tools / commands that can provide additional info for the people that could work on debugging. For example you mention sending callstack which rised my eyebrow ;) .

Comment: A call stack is basically a bread crumb trial of where you are in the program... So, if I have ran method A, which in turn calls Method B, and we have now called Method C from there (ie 2 levels of nesting) a call stack would look something like A() > B() > C().